# How to prove that $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is not a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$GL_2(\mathbb{R})=\left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \,\middle|\, a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\textrm{ and } ad-bc\neq 0\right\rbrace$

Claim: The subset $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})=\left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \,\middle|\, a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}\textrm{ and } ad-bc\neq 0\right\rbrace$ is not a subgroup.

I'm not really sure how to show this is not a subgroup. I believe it may have something to do with the inverse perhaps having a result in $\mathbb{R}$. Because I believe this group satisfies the closure, associativity and identity axioms. But, i'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Is there a mistake in the definition of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I guess $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$ for $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$

Comment: I don't believe your notation is standard. Nonetheless, notice twice the identity has no inverse in your subset and if it had an inverse it must agree with the inverse for the whole group.

Comment: @Van he means the typo

Comment: Isn't the general linear group only defined over fields? Otherwise it wouldn't be a *group* at all.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If $R$ is a ring, $\operatorname{GL}_n(R)$ typically denotes the group of units of the ring $M_n(R)$ of $n \times n$ matrices; equivalently, it is the automorphism group of the left $R$-module $R^n$. If $R$ is commutative, $\operatorname{GL}_n(R) = \{X \in M_n(R) : \det X \in R^\times\}$, where $R^\times$ is the group of units of $F$, so $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) = \{X \in M_2(\mathbb{Z}) : \det X \in \{-1,1\}\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]\in GL_2(\mathbb Z)$, but $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]^{-1}\notin GL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: Shouldn't the determinant of a matrix in $GL_2(\mathbf Z)$ be $\pm 1$?

Comment: That's the normal definition, yes. But it seems that, for the OP, the elements of $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ are the matrices from $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ whose entries are integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $A$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (or over any commutative ring) is invertible if and only if $\det(A)$ is a unit. So you should find a matrix such that its determinant is not invertible in $\mathbb{Z}$.